# Defining colours as resources in mono for android

Tags: colors, xamarin.android, selector, android-resources

I am worried that this is a duplicate question, but I have read these three questions and I'm still at a loss:

[Setting background color from colours.xml throws invalid operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734423/monodroid-setting-background-color-from-colors-xml-throws-invalidoperationexce)

[How to define variable resource such as colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111935/how-to-define-variable-resource-such-as-colours-colour-in-a-wadl)

[Colour resource ID returning wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190111/colour-resource-id-returning-wrong-value)

I'm creating a Selector for a list view and setting the background of the item view as this selector. I want the selector to reference colours that I have defined in resource file, but I cannot get the colours to be recognised.

The colours resource file:

```xml
// colors.xml .. path=Resources\color\colours.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <color name="background_default">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="background_highlighted">#FFE9E9E9</color>
    <color name="list_separator">#FFE6E6E6</color>
    <color name="highlight">#FF00AEEE</color>
    <color name="font_dark">#FF333333</color>
    <color name="font_light">#FF808080</color>
</resources>
```

The selector:

```xml
// selector.xml .. path=Resources\drawable\selector.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@color/background_default" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/background_highlighted" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/highlight" />
</selector>
```

In the item view I use this:

```cs
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

I get 3 errors that say No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/background_default'). For each of the colours referenced in selector.xml, I've set colour.xml as an android resource and I've cleaned/resetthe solution a couple of times now. There has to be something I'm missing or doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your colors to path Resources\values\Colors.xml

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the colour referencing. Problem is it doesn't like the selector now when it infaltes the list item view....

Comment: I found the problem, it was the line android:color="@color/###" it should've been android:drawable="@color/###". My mistake! I'll edit my original post to include this. Thanks.